# Java JTabbedPane - removing gap at the end of JTabbedPane row

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I was looking for answer for a while and i simply cannot find it.
Any knows how can i remove the gap that is in the end of line of tabs in JTabbedPane?

When I add many different tabs so there are like 3 lines and every got such gap in the end as it would not fit the container the JTabbedPane is in.

I use a lil bit changed BasicJTabbedPaneUI but without my own UI problem still remains.

**[Picture of Gap](http://postimg.org/image/50ximxxkh/)**

Wonder if i have to rewrite paintTabArea method or there is some other way to do it.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab width handling is done by `BasicTabbedPaneUI.TabbedPaneLayout`. Since you already use a custom UI you can as well modify the layout too. Take a look especially at `calculateTabAreaWidth()`.